# Android Webview reset Zoom second time in a fragment

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview that you can pinch to zoom just fine.  I added a context menu to allow you to reset the zoom in addition to pinching out.  However if I pinch a second time to zoom in, the same exact call to reset the zoom does not appear to reset the view?  I've tried the following in various combinations but can not get a consistent reset zoom to work  Thoughts?

```
myfrag.getWebView().getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
myfrag.getWebView().getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myfrag.getWebView().scrollTo(0,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but this works:

myfrag.getWebView().getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);                myfrag.getWebView().getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myfrag.getWebView().setInitialScale(0);